# Is it possible to connect to old p4 depots after a system format?

Tags: version-control, perforce

I am running a local p4 server for personal usage, and I had to re-install windows on my machine recently which erased all my data. Now I tried to re-install perforce in the same machine after the format, but it doesn't connect to my old p4 depots anymore and it is asking me to create new depots. So is there a way I can connect to my old p4 depots?

my details such as my systemname, IP, Email should be same as they were before the windows re-install

sorry I am a bit new to all these version control software

I appreciate the help!

Thanks!

Comment: If the depot and client were both on your local hard drive, and you didn't have your files backed up anywhere else, and you wiped that drive, the data is permanently gone.  Backups are very important!  Your best bet may be to bring the machine to a data recovery specialist so they can see if anything can be recovered from any parts of the hard drive that weren't fully wiped during the reinstall.

Comment: Damn, that Sucks! yeah, I have both my client and depot on my hard drive... I will see if I can recover that data from somewhere, @samwise Thanks for the Answer though!

Comment: It's been a couple of decades since I've self-hosted a Perforce server, but FWIW, if I were to do it today I'd probably do something like put the checkpoints and the depot archives (not the db files) in Dropbox to make sure everything stayed backed up.

Comment: Haha, Thanks for the advice! I have no idea how to do the checkpoints but I will do some google-ing to figure it out

Comment: https://www.perforce.com/manuals/p4sag/Content/P4SAG/Home-p4sag.html